# How can I save data from a Windows Form to an XML file?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5

I pretty sure I have to create some sort of mold of what the XML file has to look like first, right?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can start writing directly to an XDocument object and then save out to file using XDocument.Save(filename) method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One simple way to do this would be to create .NET classes that you put the data in and then use [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to serialize the data to a file and then later deserialize back into an instance of the class and re-populate the form.

AS an example, if you have a form with customer data. To keep it short we will just have first name and last name. You can create a class to hold the data. Keep in mind this is just a simple example, you can store arrays and all kinds of complex/nested data like this.

```
public class CustomerData
{
  public string FirstName;
  public string LastName;
}
```

So save the data as XML your code will look something like this.

```
// Create an instance of the CustomerData class and populate
// it with the data from the form.
CustomerData customer = new CustomerData();
customer.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
customer.LastName = txtLastName.Text;

// Create and XmlSerializer to serialize the data to a file
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerData));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Data.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
  xs.Serialize(fs, customer);
}
```

And loading the data back would be something like the following

```
CustomerData customer;
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerData));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("Data.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
  // This will read the XML from the file and create the new instance
  // of CustomerData
  customer = xs.Deserialize(fs) as CustomerData;
}

// If the customer data was successfully deserialized we can transfer
// the data from the instance to the form.
if (customer != null)
{
  txtFirstName.Text = customer.FirstName;
  txtLastName.Text = customer.LastName;
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the method I would suggest. The only problem you may encounter is that if your data changes, old versions will not always deserialize to the DataObject correctly. You have to write a converter to update the XML to the new schema, or write an alternate loader for the xml (based on the old schema) and then re-save it with the `XmlSerializer`

Comment: Is there any reason you decided to use a `class` and not a `struct`?

Comment: @cyclotis04, a struct is good for smallish immutable data. You end-up passing instances of the data classes around to other parts of the application so passing references is nice and efficient for large data structures. This is probably your typical struct vs. class discussion, and for me I normally go with classes unless I really understand the need and see the value of going with a struct, but that is just a rule of thumb for me.

Comment: I would also like to piggy-back on this question and ask how you might work this solution with an array or list of data.

Comment: @RobertFleck - Create a class which contains the array or list and then serialize that class. This leaves you with the possibility to add other data other than the array/list if ever required.

Answer (score 1):

look at using Linq to xml - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx
there are tutorials here that will guide you through creating and querying an xml document.

Answer (score 0):

So, are you wanting to collect data from a user in a Windows form application and then write it out to an XML file (when they click OK)?  If so, I'd check out the **XmlTextWriter** class ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx ).