# Saving windows form as xml document

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Form Save to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334949/windows-form-save-to-xml)

I would like to save the structure of a simple windows form to an XML document, upon a button click. I also need to save main properties of controls, such as text, name, size, location...

Any ideas on how to approach this assignment? Some useful links maybe?

Comment: You don't need tags in the title of your questions; the tagging system already serves this purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334949/windows-form-save-to-xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877313/how-can-i-save-data-from-a-windows-form-to-an-xml-file

Comment: Maybe you could take a look to WPF :)

Comment: Ok, so transfering the data is covered now. What about the look of the form? I know that WPF is an XML based, but i have to use the basic WF, and somehow tranform the looks of it to xml.